# Databases and try/catch

Tags: php, yii, yii2, try-catch

Im coding in PHP, with Yii2 framework, and I want to do some try/catch situation, something like this:

```
try {
   save-something
   delete-something
} catch (Exception $e) {
   put an error msg
}
```

What happens if PHP/Yii2 can save first element, but can't delete the second? The operations will be reversed? Or I get one element saved and the other one without being deleted? If the answer is case (2), what is the best approach to achieve what I need? Transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the try-catch won't do anything to rollback the changes made in line 1 if line 2 throws an exception. A way to make this happen is with transactions:

```
transaction = db.starttransaction()
try {
   transaction = db.starttransaction()
   transaction->save-something
   transaction->delete-something
   transaction->commit()
} catch (Exception $e) {
   transation->reverse()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to save and delete it in the event of a failure or that it will be more correct to use the transactions here is an example of the real when on a yii2

```
 $transaction = User::getDb()->beginTransaction();
 try {
        $user = new User();
        $user->email = 'test@gmail.com';
        $user->save();

        $transaction->commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
    }
```

[Class yii\db\Transaction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-transaction.html)